# Linking investigational drugs to name of owning company

Tags: data-request, medical, drugs

I see that AACT (https://aact.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/data_dictionary) has investigational drugs. I find the table/field: keywords/name to be useful for finding investigational drugs.

I'm wondering though how to find the name of the company that owns an investigational drug.
I'm also interested in finding drugs that are competitors / have similar effects.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used that dataset, but I can give you general guidance.

The name of the company that owns an investigational drug can have several answers. The drug could be the product of collaboration (e.g. the Pfizer/BioNTech covid vaccine), so to which company would you attribute ownership? Some ways are through the name of the drug (e.g. Merck investigational drugs start with "MK-"), or through the name of the company listed as the sponsor of the clinical trial.

For drugs with similar effects, you may need to use TF/IDF against research publications and then cluster based on frequently-used terms.

I hope this helps.